# PowerShell Streaming Output

Tags: powershell, stream, powershell-4.0, piping

I'd like to capture some streaming output in PowerShell. For example

```
cmd /c "echo hi && foo"
```

This command should print hi and then bomb. I know that I can use -ErrorVariable:

```
Invoke-Command { cmd /c "echo hi && foo" } -ErrorVariable ev
```

however there is an issue: in the case of long running commands, I want to stream the output, not capture it and only get the stderr/stdout output at the end of the command

Ideally, I'd like to be able to split stderr and stdout and pipe to two different streams - and pipe the stdout back to the caller, but be prepared to throw stderr in the event of an error. Something like

```
$stdErr
Invoke-Command "cmd" "/c `"echo hi && foo`"" `
  -OutStream (Get-Command Write-Output) `
  -ErrorAction {
    $stdErr += "`n$_"
    Write-Error $_
  }

if ($lastexitcode -ne 0) { throw $stdErr}
```

the closest I can get is using piping, but that doesn't let me discriminate between stdout and stderr so I end up throwing the entire output stream

```
function Invoke-Cmd {
<# 
.SYNOPSIS 
Executes a command using cmd /c, throws on errors.
#>
    param([string]$Cmd)
    )
    $out = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
    # I need the 2>&1 to capture stderr at all
    cmd /c $Cmd '2>&1' |% {
        $out.AppendLine($_) | Out-Null
        $_
    }

    if ($lastexitcode -ne 0) {
        # I really just want to include the error stream here
        throw "An error occurred running the command:`n$($out.ToString())" 
    }
}
```

Common usage:

```
Invoke-Cmd "GitVersion.exe" | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Note that an analogous version that just uses a ScriptBlock (and checking the output stream for [ErrorRecord]s isn't acceptable because there are many programs that "don't like" being executed directly from the  PowerShell process

The .NET System.Diagnostics.Process API lets me do this...but I can't stream output from inside the stream handlers (because of the threading and blocking - though I guess I could use a while loop and stream/clear the collected output as it comes in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: updated sample below *should* now work across PowerShell hosts.**   GitHub issue [Inconsistent handling of native command stderr](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3996)  has been opened to track the discrepancy in previous example.  Note however that as it depends on undocumented behavior, the behavior may change in the future.   Take this  into consideration before using it in a solution that must be durable.

You are on the right track with using pipes, you probably don't need Invoke-Command, almost ever.   Powershell DOES distinguish between stdout and stderr.   Try this for example:

```
cmd /c "echo hi && foo" | set-variable output
```

The `stdout` is piped on to set-variable, while std error still appears on your screen.  If you want to hide and capture the `stderr` output, try this:

```
cmd /c "echo hi && foo" 2>$null | set-variable output
```

The `2>$null` part is an undocumented trick that results in the error output getting appended to the PowerShell `$Error` variable as an `ErrorRecord`.

Here's an example that displays stdout, while trapping `stderr` with an `catch` block:

```
function test-cmd {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()

    $ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
    try {
        cmd /c foo 2>$null
    } catch {
        $errorMessage = $_.TargetObject
        Write-warning "`"cmd /c foo`" stderr: $errorMessage"
        Format-list -InputObject $_ -Force | Out-String | Write-Debug
    }
}

test-cmd
```

Generates the message:

```
WARNING: "cmd /c foo" stderr: 'foo' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

If you invoke with debug output enabled, you'll alsow see the details of the thrown ErrorRecord:

```
DEBUG: 

Exception             : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: 'foo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
TargetObject          : 'foo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ('foo' is not re...ternal command,:String) [], RemoteException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at test-cmd, <No file>: line 7
                        at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
PSMessageDetails      :
```

Setting `$ErrorActionPreference="stop"` causes PowerShell to throw an exception when the child process writes to stderr, which sounds like it's the core of what you want.   This `2>$null` trick makes the cmdlet and external command behavior very similar.

Comment: The try catch doesn't usually or seem to apply to errors thrown internally in other programs. It just sets lasterrorcode

Comment: An external program which writes to stderr isn't throwing an error, but if $errorActionPreference is set to "stop", it's PowerShell is the one turning that into a ErrorRecord and throwing it.   It has nothing to do with catching errors thrown internally to the other program.

Comment: Updated sample code to make it clearer how PowerShell is handling the stderr stream.

Comment: Then why do I ever run into situations where I need to check the lastexitcode ever though I have erroractionpreference as true

Comment: I would guess its because it is possible for an application to NOT write to stderr but still return a non-success exit code.

Comment: @Jeff: You're right: `$ErrorActionPreference` only controls the reaction to _non-terminating errors_, which is a PowerShell-internal concept.
By contrast, `Try` / `Catch` is for catching  _PowerShell terminating errors_ and  _.NET exceptions_.
As far as I know, external utilities such as `cmd` _never_ generate _either_ error - all they do is report an _exit code_, which is reflected in `$LASTEXITCODE`. The only way to convert stderr lines to PS error records is to use `2>&1` as a _PowerShell_ redirection.
In other words: I don't think this solution can work. If it does, please tells us why

Comment: Have you tried the example I provided?  It is clearly catching an exception based on cmd.exe's error message!  PS Version 5.1.15063.296.

Comment: Yes, I have, using your code as posted, on Windows PowerShell v5.1.14393.1198 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (64-bit; v10.0.14393) - no exception, just stderr passed straight through to the console. Has something changed between v5.1.14393.1198 and 5.1.15063.296?

Comment: Perhaps something has changed, I don't know, but the [internal documentation](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/02b5f357a20e6dee9f8e60e3adb9025be3c94490/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/CommandBase.cs#L268) makes it clear the design intent is that

> setting shell variable ErrorActionPreference to "Stop" will cause the command to stop when an otherwise non-terminating error occurs.

Comment: I just tried in v6-beta.2, and I see the same behavior I've described. As I've stated,  the concepts of _non-terminating_ and _terminating_ errors only apply to _native PowerShell commands_. I've summarized my findings in my answer - do tell me which claims I'm making are incorrect, if any. Conversely, I'm genuinely curious to learn how and why your environment differs. Is your `cmd.exe` not the stock Windows one?

Comment: Burt, now that the current, undocumented `2>$null` behavior has been [classified as a bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4002) and is likely to go away, can I suggest you not recommend it as a solution?

Comment: I don't know how soon it will be going away, nor what if any alternative will accompany a change, but I acknowledge that the behavior may change in the future, and have added a warning to that effect.   Thanks @mkement0.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>- **The behavior described applies to running PowerShell in *regular console/terminal windows* with *no remoting* involved.** With remoting and in the *ISE*, the behavior is different as of PSv5.1 - see bottom.

- The **`2>$null` behavior that [Burt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44491420/45375) relies on** - `2>$null` secretly still writing to PowerShell's error stream and therefore, with `$ErrorActionPreference` `Stop` in effect, *aborting* the script as soon as an external utility writes *anything* to stderr - **has been [classified as a bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4002) and is likely to go away.**</sup>

- When PowerShell invokes an external utility such as `cmd`, its stderr output is passed straight through by default. That is, stderr output prints straight to the console, without being included in captured output (whether by assigning to a variable or redirecting to a file).
- While you can use `2>&1` *as part of the `cmd` command line*, you won't be able to distinguish between stdout and stderr output in PowerShell.
- By contrast, **if you use `2>&1` as a *PowerShell* redirection, you can filter the success stream based on the input objects' type**:

  - A `[string]` instance is a *stdout* line
  - A `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instance is a *stderr* line.

The following function, `Invoke-CommandLine`, takes advantage of this:

- Note that the `cmd /c` part isn't built in, so you would invoke it as follows, for instance:

  ```
  Invoke-CommandLine 'cmd /c "echo hi && foo"'
  ```
- There is no *fundamental* difference between passing invocation of a `cmd` command line and direct invocation of an external utility such as `git.exe`, but do note that only invocation via `cmd` allows use of *multiple* commands via operators `&`, `&&`, and `||`, and that only `cmd` interprets `%...%`-style environment-variable references, *unless* you use `--%`, the stop-parsing symbol.
- `Invoke-CommandLine` outputs both stdout and stderr line as they're being received, so you can use the function in a pipeline.

  - As written, stderr lines are written to PowerShell's error stream using `Write-Error` as they're being received, with a *single, generic* exception being thrown after the external command terminates, should it report a nonzero `$LASTEXITCODE`.
  - It's easy to adapt the function:

    - to take action once the first stderr line is received.
    - to *collect* all stderr lines in a single variable
    - and/or, after termination, to take action if *any* stderr input was received, even with `$LASTEXITCODE` reporting `0`.
- `Invoke-CommandLine` uses `Invoke-Expression`, so the usual caveat applies: be sure you know what command line you're passing, because it will be executed as-is, no matter what it contains.

---

```
function Invoke-CommandLine {
<# 
.SYNOPSIS 
Executes an external utility with stderr output sent to PowerShell's error           '
stream, and an exception thrown if the utility reports a nonzero exit code.   
#>

  param([parameter(Mandatory)][string] $CommandLine)

  # Note that using . { ... } is required around the Invoke-Expression
  # call to ensure that the 2>&1 redirection works as intended.
  . { Invoke-Expression $CommandLine } 2>&1 | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]) { # stderr line
      Write-Error $_  # send stderr line to PowerShell's error stream
    } else { # stdout line
      $_              # pass stdout line through
    } 
  }

  # If the command line signaled failure, throw an exception.
  if ($LASTEXITCODE) {
    Throw "Command failed with exit code ${LASTEXITCODE}: $CommandLine"
  }

}
```

---

#### Optional reading: how calls to external utilities fit into PowerShell's error handling

<sup>Current as of: Windows PowerShell v5.1, PowerShell Core v6-beta.2</sup>

- The value of preference variable **`$ErrorActionPreference` only controls the reaction to errors and .NET exceptions that occur *in PowerShell cmdlet/function calls or expressions***.
- **`Try` / `Catch` is for catching  *PowerShell's terminating errors* and  *.NET exceptions*.**
- ***In a regular console window with no remoting involved*, external utilities such as `cmd` currently *never* generate *either* error** - all they do is **report an *exit code***, which PowerShell reflects in **automatic variable `$LASTEXITCODE`**, and automatic variable `$?` reflects `$False` if the exit code is nonzero.

  - Note: The fact **that the behavior differs fundamentally in hosts other than the console host - which includes the Windows ISE and when remoting is involved - is problematic**: There, calls to external utilities result in **stderr output treated as if *non-terminating errors* had been reported**; specifically:

    - Every stderr output line is output as an error record and also recorded in the automatic `$Error` collection.
    - In *addition* to `$?` being set to `$false` with a nonzero exit code, the presence of any stderr output *also* sets it to `$False`.
    - **This behavior is problematic**, as stderr output by itself does not necessarily indicate an *error* - only a *nonzero exit code* does.
    - [Burt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776535/burt-harris) has created an [issue in the PowerShell GitHub repository to discuss this inconsistency](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3996).
  - ***By default*, stderr output generated by an external utility is *passed straight through to the console*** - they are *not* captured by PowerShell variable assignments or (success-stream) output redirections.
  - As discussed above, this can be changed:

    - **`2>&1` *as part of a command line passed to `cmd`*** sends stdout and stderr *combined* to PowerShell's success stream, as *strings*, with no way to distinguish between whether a given line was a stdout or stderr line.
    - **`2>&1` as a *PowerShell redirection* sends stderr lines to PowerShell's success stream too, but *you can distinguish between stdout- and stderr-originated lines by their DATA TYPE***: a `[string]`-typed line is a stdout-originated line, whereas a `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`-typed line is a stderr-originated one.

Comment: Oh, the part about redirecting in PowerShell w/ `2>&1` and filtering on type `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` is interesting.   Too bad it depends so much on where the redirection happens.   That makes it hard to explain to people, but you've done an admirable job.